# jQuery filter - item position

Tags: jquery

Very briefly - 
[jQuery filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) lets you filter through a list of jQuery objects. It also takes in a jQuery object as a parameter which is really cool.

Now, say I have a list of elements x - [div1, div2, div3, div4] and I have a jQuery object y which refers to div4.

I can get div4 out of said list by simply using `x.filter(y)` but is there a simple way to get the index of y in x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) method

```
x.index(y)
```

Comment: why I didn't think of that, I still don't get. Thank you